# How to download .epub file in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

hi I'm new in iPhone development. 
I'm trying to load content from link in a webview which is .epub file but however webview cant load the requested page. I don't know what is the problem.

Can any body suggest solution for it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"];'

Answer (score 1):

epub is just XHTML stored in a zipfile XML. Get a zip library and you can use a `UIWebView` to display the actual content.

Get zip library for iPhone SDK from this link ..[ziparchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/)

This ZipArchive is an Objective-C class to compress or uncompress zip files, which is base on open source code "MiniZip".

It can be used for iPhone application development, and cocoa on Mac OSX as well.

i hope this helped you..

Comment: You know, iOS comes with libz.  There's no need for another zip lib.

Comment: yes i know about libz library dude but here i post the link with information about it dude.. :)

Comment: @CodaFi here user wants to display or open data from epub file so here this ziparchive sdk is very easy to use and good example for it dude.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`EPUB` is just `XHTML` stored in a `zipfile` with an `XML` manifest. Get a `zip` library and you `unzip` it & can use a `WebView` to display the actual content.

Comment: but UIWebView cant load the request how can i unzip it

Comment: use the zipArchive library which @paras shared.